# update multiple records in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I am working on a CodeIgniter project where i have to change the status of record. Actually I have to update only those records whose id are/is in the ids sting.

Currently, only one record is updated with my code. My model function is:

```
public function markUnRead() {
    $ids = 1,2,3,4,5,6;
    $update = array('status' => 0);
    $this->db->where_in('id', $ids);
    $this->db->update('tableName',$update);

    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Someone help me please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter of [`where_in()`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) method should be an `array`:

```php
$this->db->where_in('id', array(1,2,3,4,5,6));
```

By any reason, if the `$ids` is an string like `"1,2,3,4,5,6"`, you could get it to work by:

```php
$ids = explode(',', $ids);
$this->db->where_in('id', $ids);
```

Comment: I made the second parameter array but still got the same result. only one record is updated.

Comment: yes brother it works now , thank you very much, actually my changes were not correct. You answer is absolutely right. thanks once again.

Comment: I have the same problem and I have applied the same solution which you suggest here but I could not update multiple values, only single values get updated. What to do in this conditions? @HashemQolami